# Where do you put the logic with a Logic-less Template System

Tags: javascript, php, templates, mustache

So I've a bunch of pages that pull in entities with ajax and put them in the DOM with Mustache.

Each entity has a created_on field, which is a MySQL DateTime, however only the string representation of the DateTimes are passed to Mustache.
I understand that Mustache is logic-less, but what's the most appropriate place for this logic to go.

Should I loop over each entity and convert the created_on field to a date in the appropriate format in the model or is there some other more appropriate place for it?

EDIT:

```
class ExampleController {
    private $dataModel;
    private $presenter;

    public function __construct(
        DataModel $dataModel,
        Presenter $presenter
    ){
        $this->dataModel = $dataModel;
        $this->presenter = $presenter;
    }

    /**
    * Action loads data from model and returns it for Mustache
    *
    */
    public function exampleAction() 
    {
        /**
        * Pull data from database
        */
        $data = $this->dataModel->getData();
        // $data = [// <-- Sample Data
        //  [
        //      'id' => 1,
        //      'created_on' => '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
        //  ],
        //  [
        //      'id' => 2,
        //      'created_on' => '2015-02-03 00:00:00'
        //  ],
        //  [
        //      'id' => 3,
        //      'created_on' => '2015-04-05 00:00:00'
        //  ]
        // ];

        /**
        * Make data presentable
        */
        $presentableData = $this->presenter->makePresentable($data);

        /**
        * Return presentable data for Mustache
        */
        echo json_encode($presentableData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends on the breakdown. Generally this is done in the "Controller" - what which calls the template (or binds the "View" with the "Model"). Generate the data that *represents* the view and then give that to mustache. While Mustache doesn't have 'logic' per se it effectively supports for-each/if-true/if-false flow control statements; and Mustache also supports Helper Functions.

Comment: So the controller grabs the data (a collection of entities) and then loops over the collection, modifying the fields (if necessary) for the view? Are we on the same page?

Comment: Well, no, you'd create a new tree as needed for the problem domain - not mucking with the existing data / model.. If the transformation itself is not about 'logic' but about rendering a value differently a Helper would appropriate. The Model really has no right to care how it's displayed.

Comment: Awesome - So Im basically looking for Mustache helpers.

Comment: For non-logic (as in non-structure control and non-data fetch) value transformations, probably.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a logic-less template language, you move your logic into code. One place to put it is the Controller, but that's really not the best.

It's better to think of your View as consisting of two parts: one part template, and one part code. You might call this code a ViewModel, or a Presenter, or you might even call it the View, because once you do this, the template itself is the least interesting bit of what is typically done by the View.

Then, the controller is responsible for handling the "action" bit of a request, loading domain model(s) and passing everything to the View(s)/ViewModel(s)/Presenter(s) to render.

Here are a couple of examples of this approach:

[Mustache.php : Idiomatic ways to template select dropdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358228/mustache-php-idiomatic-ways-to-template-select-dropdowns/12753087#12753087)

https://gist.github.com/bobthecow/61161639d8be82a75b5e

Comment: Please see sample controller code added to question above. If I wanted to modify the created_on dates in the model data, should these modifications take place inside $this->presenter->makePresentable() ? For example I might loop over $data, and modify each date into the desired format.

Comment: You could massage your data at either end, to be honest. If you've already got server-side things that would help with it, you could use the presenter like you stubbed out. It's just as valid to pass data from the data model straight to the frontend and add a presenter layer in javascript.

Comment: So you can add this presentation logic in javascript right before you wrap the entities in the Mustache templates, or you do it server side, right before you json encode the data and send it to the client. Thanks for clarifying that.